# Display number of entries next to Date Area in Calendar View

Tags: lotus-domino, hcl-notes

I'm trying to complete a request in Domino Notes 11.x.
We have got an a view which is displayed as a calendar view, this works fine however the request is to be able to display the number of entries for a day, ideally next to the Date Area or if not, anywhere else so the end user see's the number of entries.

I hope some Domino/Notes Guru could give me advise to if this is possible and and/or guide me how to achieve this.

thank you all

If needed I will update my question with some more details and screenshots